# Foreground or background image manipulations in Rails (Jruby, Torquebox)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, jruby, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I have uploading photos with ajax, manipulations and uploading to s3 take a lot of time. I heard that it's better to complete that tasks on background. My app need to wait while photos become uploaded. But if I choose background way then I will need to work with websockets or repeat ajax to check result(links to s3) ( I'm not happy about this).
Why is it too bad to make hard calculations right in controller (foreground)? 
Now I use Torquebox(Jruby) and as I understand it has perfect concurrency. Does it mean that waiting uploading to s3 will not take resources and all will work fine?
Please write about pros and cons of back/fore ground in my situation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally considered bad practice to block a web request handler on a network request to a third party service. If that service should become slow or unavailable, this can clog up all your web processes, regardless of what ruby you are using. This is what you are referring to as 'foreground.'

Essentially this is the flow of your current setup (in foreground):

1. a user uploads an image on your site and your desired controller receives the request.
2. Your controller makes a **synchronous** request to s3. This is a **blocking** request.
3. Your controller waits
4. Your controller waits
5. Your controller (continues) to wait
6. finally, (and this is not guaranteed) you receive a response from s3 and your code continues and renders your given view/json/text/etc.

Clearly steps 3-5 are very bad news for your server, and as I stated earlier, this worker/thread/process (Depending on your ruby/rails server framework) will be 'held up' until the response from s3 is received (which potentially could never happen).

Here is the same flow with a background job with some javascript help on the front-end for notification:

1. a user uploads an image on your site and your desired controller receives the request.
2. Your controller creates a **new thread/process** to make the request to s3. This is a **non-blocking** approach. You set a flag on a record that references your s3 image src, for example completed: false and your **code continues nicely to step 3**. Your new thread/process will be the one waiting for a response from s3 now, and you will set the 'completed' flag to true when s3 responds.
3. You render your view/json/text/etc, and inherently **release your worker/thread/process** for this request...good news!

now for the fun front end stuff:

4. your client receives your response, triggering your front-end javascript to start a setInterval-like repetitive function that 'pings' your server every 3-ish seconds, where your back-end controller checks to see if the 'completed' flag that you set earlier is true, and if so, respond/render true.
5. your client side javascript receives your response and either continues to ping (until you designate that it should give up) or stop pinging because your app responded true.

I hope this sets you on the right path. I figured writing code for this answer was inferior because it seemed like you were looking for pros and cons. For actual implementation ideas, I would look into the following:

- the [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is excellent for solving the background job issues described here. It will handle creating the new process where you can make the request to s3.
- here is an excellent [railscast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjZT3Y3WhcU) that will help you get a better understanding of the code.

Comment: 1. I read about thread pools, and (as I understand) my application in jruby(java) will use fixed thread pool. It means that a lot of image uploads in one time can stop all threads, when system resources end.  Am I correct?
2. And could you answer, are repeatable requests good enough? For good client I need to send at least one request per second. ( Are websockets use-case for this? I will not use them in first version, but for future thinking.)
Thank you very much!

Comment: @makrusak, you are correct that a lot of image uploads could consume your max request pool size if you are doing a synchronous upload from your app server to a third party. This would slow things down due to requests queuing up, as I explained above. What do you mean by 'repeatable requests'? and 'one request per second'? Websockets are excellent if you prefer real-time responses to and from a client when making a requests. This does not bypass the synchronous upload issue though, as I explained. Websockets would only replace the 'pinging' ajax requests. Let me know if you need any more help.